# How to resolve Virtual Wifi Miniport adapter driver problems?

Tags: laptop, wireless-networking, acer-aspire

I am trying to access my home wireless internet and the troubleshooting screen says Microsoft Virtual Wifi Miniport adapter has a driver problem. What does this mean?

I have a Acer 5532 Series laptop.

Comment: what operating system is your Acer laptop running?

Comment: @studiohack: I think Vista/7, I think that Windows XP didn't have virtual miniport adapters yet.

Answer (score 1):

I have an ACER4741G - I installed some software at some stage as well as Windows Updates. Suddenly my Wi-Fi did not work any more. Solution:

- Download free AVG Antivirus, install and run
- Download AVG PC Tuneup 2011 (free to use for one time), install and run

After this my Wi-Fi is working again.